# My python "for" loop is stopping after 4 times, its supposed to go through 7 loops, why is that?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
colors= ["blue", "pink", "red", "white", "green", "orange", "black", "purple"]
colors.sort()
print (colors)

message= "we decided to remove "

for color in colors:

    removed_color = colors.pop (-1)
    print(message.title() + removed_color.title() + " from the list".title())
    print (  ("colors remaining ".title()) + str(len(colors)).title() )
```

Comment: You're mutating `colors` during the for loop by calling `pop`, which is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating from the start of the list, and removing from the end of the list, so by the time you are halfway through the list you have run out of list.  Instead of using a `for` loop, you should instead use a `while` loop.

```
colors= ["blue", "pink", "red", "white", "green", "orange", "black", "purple"]
colors.sort()
print (colors)

message= "we decided to remove "

while colors:
    removed_color = colors.pop (-1)
    print(message.title() + removed_color.title() + " from the list".title())
    print (  ("colors remaining ".title()) + str(len(colors)).title() )
```

The `while colors` loop will continue as long as any colors remain in the list.

Comment: thanks a lot! it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're looping through the list and also mutating the list while doing that and always removing the last item on each iteration till the mutated list has reached the largest possible index with the loop count.